# Build failed... No build tools defined. AVR studio 4.19

Tags: avr

When I tried to debug a small piece of code using AVR studio 4 I got this error:

```
Build failed... No build tools defined.
```

Could someone give me some advices?

Answer (score 10):

In AVRStudio 4.19, Atmel made some serious changes from previous versions. Specially while using the toolchains. After you install [WinAVR](http://winavr.sourceforge.net/download.html) (the latest version, 2010...), open a new project in Avrstudio and from now on, everytime you make a new project you have to do this steps:

1. Go to "Project" tab
2. Go to "Configurations Options"
3. Then all the way down to "Custom Options".
4. Once you there, you'll see a checkbox called "Use AVR ToolChain", UNCHECK that option.(For some reason AVRStudio 4.19 does not link automatically the toolchain from WINAVR, so you have to do it manually).
5. After this, it enables the two options below.
6. For `avr-gcc`, you browse to the next direction: `C:\ProgramFiles\WINAVR20100110\bin\avr-gcc.exe`
7. For `make`, you browse to the next direction: `C:\ProgramFiles\WINAVR20100110\utils\bin\make.exe`

**This directions depends on where did you installed WINAVR. I remember that the default location is "C:\" but when I installed WINAVR, I changed it to "ProgramFiles"**

8. Click "OK".

After doing this steps, you should be able to compile and run your code. 
Cheers, and hope it helped!

PD: I had that same problem, months ago. Check out, www.avrfreaks.net, very good webpage for newbies and pros at programming AVRs.

Comment: If you have problem like this: ../WiegandSuomi.c:42: fatal error: opening dependency file dep/WiegandSuomi.o.d: No such file or directory Replace your msys file in WinAVR (http://www.avrfreaks.net/comment/429552#comment-429552)

Answer (score 1):

You need to install WinAVR or Atmel's "AVR Toolchain." If you already have one of these and still get this message, you may need to tweak the System Variables.

Answer (score 1):

Connect the programmer first and then run avr studio.

Answer (score 0):

I have that error when I try to open a project made in another version of AVR Studio (or upgraded to another version by someone else).